# How to not keep last item copied?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm creating Word documents and adding images using Excel VBA.

Since I want images to fit half the width of the page, I create a temporary document with a layout of two columns and paste the image there first, then cut and paste it in the document I really need.

The temporary document closes after it is used. When the program closes the Main document and creates another one, a pop up comes up asking if I want to keep the last item copied. How do I close this window or say "no" to it from VBA?

That being said, the program keeps going, and ignores the pop up but it is annoying to have the program not closed, when I explicitly said so.

After all the documents are created, many windows of Microsoft Word remain open with this pop up in each. I guess it also holds images in memory so that's not good either.

```
Sub Newdoc_withImages()

    Dim wdapp As Word.Application
    Dim doct As Documents
    Dim imag As Variant
    .
    .
    *more variables*
    
    Set wdapp = New Word.Application
    With wdapp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        .Documents.Add "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Template.dot"
        .Selection.GoTo (*I position the cursor and write some things in preparation to add image*)
        If condition (*are there any images available? If yes create Temporal Document and give two columns layout for it*)
            .Documents.Add
            .Documents(1).PageSetup.TextColumns.Add Width:=InchesToPoints(2.85), EvenlySpaced:=True
            For Each imag In imgcollection 
                If condition (*If True, take the image and paste it in the Temporal Doc, then cut it to paste it in the document created at the beginning*)
                    .Documents(1).Select
                    .Documents(1).InlineShapes.AddPicture Filename:=imag, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
                    .Documents(1).InlineShapes(1).Select
                    .Selection.Cut
                    .Documents(2).Select
                    .Selection.GoTo (*Position to paste the img*)
                    .Selection.Paste
                    imgcollection.Remove (imag) (*here I remove the image from my collection, not relevant*)
                End If
            Next imag
            (*The Temporal Document actually closes*)
            .Documents(1).Close 0
            (*I return to the Document I actually care, ready for the next batch of images if I need to add more for given condition*)
            .ActiveDocument.Select
        End If
        .DisplayAlerts = 0 (*I tried these to close any pop up maybe I'm wrong, because It doesn't seem to work either*)
        .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 (objSubFolder.Path & "\" & StrConv(NamesxCrear.Items(i), vbProperCase))
        .ActiveDocument.Close (*HERE is where the pop up window comes up asking me if I want to keep the last item copied, I don't know how to close it from here*)
        .Application.Quit (*doesn't actually quit, program reamins open because of the pop up*)
    
    End With

End Sub
```

This is what the pop up looks like:
[image: This is what the pop up looks like]

Answer (score 3):

Answered by Doug Robbins on MS's website: [Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/would-you-like-to-keep-the-last-item-you-copied-if/5d2fb8a1-4779-4dd6-a644-a5edf28abc4f)

> If you create the following macro in the Normal.dotm template or an add-in, that message will no longer appear
>
> ```
> Sub FileClose()
> Dim MyData   As DataObject
> Set MyData = New DataObject
> MyData.SetText ""
> MyData.PutInClipboard
> ActiveDocument.Close
> End Sub
> ```
>
> It replaces the contents of the clipboard with a null string and then closes the document when you use File>Close.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I'm not that good implementing it. What I did was just change the .Visible = False and eliminate .Activate in the code. That way I won't see anything and all will run in the background. It doesn't solve the problem in the background, but it's good enough so I won't have to close every pop up. I had .Visible =  True because I wanted to make sure it was running ok, but there was that problema.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are done with something you copied to the clipboard you should issue the command:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

This is especially important when working with large objects like pictures. Put it right after your `.Paste` command.

Comment: Isn't the problem  with *Word*, not Excel? Wondering if this will actually work, since `Application.CutCopyMode` is from the Excel Object Model.

Comment: @BigBen Word is being automated from Excel VBA in this case so the CutCopyMode would be available.

Comment: It would be available, but does that mean it fixes the issue? I'm not sure and am wondering if it can be tested/confirmed.

Comment: I tried it without success unfortunately. Anyway thank you.  What I did was just change the .Visible = False and eliminate .Activate in the code. That way I won't see anything and all will run in the background. It doesn't solve the problem in the background, but it's good enough so I won't have to close every pop up. I had .Visible =  True because I wanted to make sure it was running ok, but there was that problema.

Comment: Sounds like you still have large objects in your clipboard taking up memory. These won't be cleared with the application is closed. You should do what @Peyter suggests and fill the clipboard with a zero sized item. That should keep your memory clean. Or stop using the clipboard at all. That's for users, not for programs.

Answer (score 1):

The shorter version of the predecessor: just before closing the document I use:

```
.Documents(1).Characters(1).Copy
```

It automatically clears big copied item.

Answer (score 0):

Copying something small into clipboard worked for me e.g.:

```
Selection.Collapse
Selection.SetRange(0, 1)
Selection.Copy
```